# How can I add custom validation rules to a new User registration?

Tags: users

For example, how might we ensure that `firstName` is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing the `users.onBeforeSave` event runs after validation, which means that we can’t add errors to the user easily.

The solution I’ve currently come up with is a plugin that adds custom validation rules to a user model, as well as a controller to handle the form submission.

## Model

Firstly, I’ve extended the `UserModel` and added custom validation rules as needed.

```php
<?php

namespace Craft;

class MyPlugin_UserModel extends UserModel
{
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        // Get the rules defined in UserModel
        $rules = parent::defineAttributes();

        // Add custom rules
        $rules['firstName'] = array(AttributeType::String, 'required' => true);
        $rules['lastName'] = array(AttributeType::String, 'required' => true);

        // If it’s a new user, require the password
        $isNewUser = !isset($this->id);
        if ($isNewUser) {
            $rules['password'] = array(AttributeType::String, 'required' => true);
        }

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

## Controller

Secondly, I’ve created a controller action that will handle form submissions. This populates our custom user model with the input and runs the standard `validate()` flow.

```php
<?php

namespace Craft;

class MyPlugin_UsersController extends BaseController
{
    protected $allowAnonymous = array('actionSaveUser');

    public function actionSaveUser()
    {
        $this->requirePostRequest();

        // Get input
        $post = craft()->request->getPost();

        // Create an instance of our model
        $user = new MyPlugin_UserModel($post);

        if (!$user->validate()) {
            // Add any errors from the validation to the user
            $user->addErrors($user->getContent()->getErrors());

            // Respond with errors
            if (craft()->request->isAjaxRequest()) {
                $this->returnJson(array(
                    'errors' => $user->getErrors(),
                ));
            } else {
                craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('Couldn’t save user.'));

                // Send the account back to the template
                craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
                    'account' => $user
                ));
            }
        } else {
            // If all is well, run the default UsersController method
            craft()->runController('users/saveUser');
        }
    }
}
```

## Template

For reference, here’s the action input in the template. Essentially, it’s just prepending the plugin handle before the default action.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myPlugin/users/saveUser">
```

Answer (score 3):

In a plugin, you can use the [onBeforeSaveUser](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#users-onBeforeSaveUser) event.

In your plugin's main file, use the following init function:

```
public function init(){
    //Tap into the onBeforeSaveUser event
    craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {

        //Get the user object from the raised event
        $user = $event->params['user'];

        //If the first name is blank, do not allow the save to continue
        if($user->firstName == '')
        {
            $event->performAction = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron. That was my first port of call, however it doesn’t allow for validation (in a single request).

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue myself. I have custom fields assigned to the user model in the dashboard that weren't being validated.

Marking those fields are required in the dashboard for the user model was all I had to do to ensure that they are required using the standard Craft saveUser controller. Depending on what your validation needs are this might work for you too.